# Determine the pH and pOH of pure water at 50 °C

Tags: ph

> Determine the pH and pOH of pure water at 50 °C.

I’m not sure what formulas to use on this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! We have a site policy for homework questions which can also apply to self-study questions. Please edit your question to include your thoughts, where you got stuck, and let us know where you're finding difficulty so we may best help you.

Comment: Use the same formula as for 25°C. The key is not the formula, but information you have to search for.

Comment: Think of Delta G vs. T

Comment: According to the “Self-ionization of water” article in wiki, the pKw of water at 50 degrees Celcius is 13.26. There is a nice table for other temperatures.